# prometheus_client custom metrics with Flask

Tags: python, flask, prometheus

I am trying to service custom Prometheus metrics through Flask. Looking at https://github.com/prometheus/client_python, I have a code similar to:

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
from prometheus_client import make_wsgi_app

# Create my app
app = Flask(__name__)

# Add prometheus wsgi middleware to route /metrics requests
app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, {
    '/metrics': make_wsgi_app()
})
```

With this setup, I'm not really sure where I should declare my custom metrics?

Comment: Your custom metrics are automatically registered when you create them and they will be exposed in `/metrics`. What is exactly your question about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by registering my custom collector to the REGISTRY with

```
REGISTRY.register(CustomCollector())
```

and then using

```
DispatcherMiddleware(
    app.wsgi_app, {"/metrics": make_wsgi_app(REGISTRY),}
)
```